How do I create a Google calendar meet event using a service account?
Event creation is implemented by the function:
func CreateEvent(startDate time.Time, duration int, headerText string) (string, error) {
    endDate := startDate.Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(duration))
    event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary:     headerText,
        Description: "AutomateCreate",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: startDate.Format(time.RFC3339),
            TimeZone: "Europe/Moscow",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: endDate.Format(time.RFC3339),
            TimeZone: "Europe/Moscow",
        },
        ConferenceData: &calendar.ConferenceData{
            CreateRequest: &calendar.CreateConferenceRequest{
                ConferenceSolutionKey: &calendar.ConferenceSolutionKey{
                    Type: "hangoutsMeet",
                },
                RequestId: uuid.New().String(),
            },
        },
    }
    event, err := calendarService.Events.Insert("calendar@gmail.com", event).ConferenceDataVersion(1).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err

    }
    text := event.Summary + "\n" + event.HangoutLink
    return text, nil
}

I get an error:
googleapi: Error 400: Invalid conference type value., invalid
Moreover, an event is created without a meet/
I'm use library link calendar/v3

Your code works for me albeit using a Workspace account and a domain-wide delegated Service Account impersonating the account.

I delegated the calendar, created a service account, enabled the meetings and calendar api, can you tell me how you delegated? Maybe that's the problem?

Here's your code plus Service Account impersonation.
This works for me: the event is created with a Hangout and the Hangout URL is returned.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func main() {
    scopes := []string{
        calendar.CalendarScope,
    }

    key := os.Getenv("KEY")
    b, err := os.ReadFile(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(b, scopes...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    subject := os.Getenv("EMAIL")
    config.Subject = subject

    ctx := context.Background()
    client := config.Client(ctx)
    opts := []option.ClientOption{
        option.WithHTTPClient(client),
    }
    calendarService, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    startDate := time.Now()
    duration := 60

    endDate := startDate.Add(time.Minute * time.Duration(duration))

    headerText := "Stackoverflow: 79290245"

    event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary:     headerText,
        Description: "AutomateCreate",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: startDate.Format(time.RFC3339),
            TimeZone: "US/Pacific",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: endDate.Format(time.RFC3339),
            TimeZone: "US/Pacific",
        },
        ConferenceData: &calendar.ConferenceData{
            CreateRequest: &calendar.CreateConferenceRequest{
                ConferenceSolutionKey: &calendar.ConferenceSolutionKey{
                    Type: "hangoutsMeet",
                },
                RequestId: uuid.New().String(),
            },
        },
    }
    resp, err := calendarService.Events.Insert(subject, event).ConferenceDataVersion(1).Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)

    }
    slog.Info("Result",
        "summary", resp.Summary,
        "hangoutLink", resp.HangoutLink)
}

